# Запись и чтение файлов в общую внутреннюю память устройства

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как записать или прочитать файл из  общей внутренней памяти устройства (`storage/emulated/0`).? Где указывать путь? Если можно, поделитесь кусочком кода.)

Имеется ввиду та область в которой сохраняются телефонная книга когда мы ее экспортируем. Не внутренней памяти области приложения. Почему то у меня не получается. стандартными способами(т.е. создание объекта File).

Вообще задача стоит такая:

1. экспорт файла во внутреннюю общедоступную область памяти устройства.
2. импорт файла из внутреней общедоступной области памяти устройства. По типу как работает FileManeger.

Comment: Проверьте имеет ли приложение разрешение на доступ к памяти

Comment: Вы про вот это или есть еще какое-нибудь?                                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Да. Еще такой момент был, что разрешение в манифесте указал, но код на создание файла отказывался работать, пока конкретно не зашел в свойства приложения и там включил переключатель на разрешение памяти (а если не указать в манифесте разрешение, то этого переключателя небыло). Мне в корень памяти было не обязательно, поэтому решил вопрос, создавая файл в родной папке приложения, там создавался без вопросов.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно необходимо было установить разрешение на запись в устройстве. У меня ОС MIUI 9.5.9.0 Стабильная. Это Android 7.1.2.

Comment: Может опубликуете ответ? Может кому то пригодится?

Comment: Рад, что помог)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте зайти в свойства приложения, затем в управление разрешениями и посмотрите в каком положении находится переключатель для разрешения доступа к памяти. Был такой момент, что разрешение в манифесте указал, но код на создание файла отказывался работать, пока конкретно не зашел в свойства приложения и там включил переключатель на разрешение памяти (а если не указать в манифесте разрешение, то этого переключателя небыло) (аппарат Xiaomi Redmi Note 4). Мне в корень памяти было не обязательно, поэтому решил вопрос, создавая файл в родной папке приложения, там создавался без вопросов.